# Select paths from traversal and filter on the destination vertex (OrientDB)

Tags: graph, orientdb, shortest-path, graph-traversal

I am new to graph databases and OrientDB, so I appreciate your patience.

I have the following SQL query to produce an expanded set of results for the *shortest* path between two vertices (I am using the GratefulDeadConcerts database):

```
select expand(sp) from (select shortestPath(#9:2,#9:15,'BOTH') as sp)
```

For whatever reason, using expand without aliasing produces no results, but that isn't really an issue.

What I want is not the *shortest* path, but a collection of *potential* paths and branches.

I have tried playing with travesedVertex:

```
SELECT traversedVertex(-1) FROM ( TRAVERSE out() FROM #9:2 WHILE $depth <= 10 )
```

But I don't know how to set the destination, or (honestly) how to interpret the results I get.

**EDIT**
If there are multiple ways to get from A to B, I want each of those paths returned as a set, something like:

```
{
   paths: [
      [#9:2, #4:16, #8:7, #9:15],
      [#9:2, #4:2, #16:5, #11:3, #9:15],
      [#9:2, #4:4, #11:6, #9:15]
   ]
}
```

Thank you for your help.

Comment: Have I answered your question ?

Comment: This is what my query does already. There is just no other path that has #9:15 as a destination starting from #9:2.

Comment: Thank you, now I understand.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, $path is the string representation of the current path.
Second, you can filter on the destination columns on the where clause of the outer query. Try this :

```
SELECT 
   $path 
FROM 
   ( TRAVERSE 
        out() 
     FROM 
        #9:2 
     WHILE 
        $depth <= 10 ) 
WHERE 
   @rid = #9:15
```

I get the following output : 
[image: query result]

Is this what you are looking for ?

If I don't add the where clause, I get this output : 
  [image: query result without where]

Comment: This helps me understand the path. What I don't get is how to get multiple paths. I've edited my question

Comment: My query syntax would allow you to get multiple paths but the traverse has only one path that goes to the specified destination

Comment: I have answered your initial question so can you please mark my answer as correct and make another post for the other question if you think it is different...